# using pyparsing with readline tab completion

Tags: python-3.x, readline, pyparsing, tab-completion

Using pyparsing is it possible to get the results of the parse up until the point when a ParseException was thrown? I would like to use pyparsing to generate a list of appropriate readline tab completions for user input so expect to have a parseException since the input will not yet be complete at the time the user presses tab for tab completion options.